# read the data frame another data frame based on a relation table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different data frames. The first one is a table that shows the relation between the ids of the other two data frame. Here is:

```py
df_related_id = pd.DataFrame()
df_related_id ['id_1'] = [1, 2, 3,4]
df_related_id ['id_2'] = [10, 10, 10,5]
      id_1  id_2
 0     1    10
 1     2    10
 2     3    10
 3     4     5
```

The second one is as follow:

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2['id_2'] = [10, 10, 10, 5,5, 30]
df_2['date'] = ['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-11-31','2017-11-31', '2017-12-31']
df_2 ['hour'] = ['6:00', '6:15', '6:00', '6:00', '6:00', '6:00']
df_2 ['val'] = [-1,12,-1,11,11,14]
df_2

     id_2     date    hour  val
 0    10  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
 1    10  2017-12-31  6:15   12
 2    10  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
 3     5  2017-11-31  6:00   11
 4     5  2017-11-31  6:00   11
 5    30  2017-12-31  6:00   14
```

So, I want to get the data based on id_1 from the second dataframe. Here is the desired output which I want. Could you please help me with that?

```
     id_1       date  hour  val
 0     1  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
 1     1  2017-12-31  6:15   12
 2     2  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
 3     2  2017-12-31  6:15   12
 4     3  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
 5     3  2017-12-31  6:15   12
 6     4  2017-11-31  6:00   11
```

Comment: "I want to get the data based on id_1 from the second dataframe". Which logic do you want to apply? Venturing a guess from looking at the input and desired output: in `df_2`, for duplicate rows (equal on `[df_2.id_2, .date, .hour`, but NOT  necessarily on `.val`), keep only the first row (e.g. keep `10, 2017-12-31, 6:00, -1`, not `10, 2017-12-31, 6:00, 13`. Next, get all matches for `id_2` in `id_1` (e.g. for `10`: `[1,2,3]`, and create rows with each of these ids: so: `1, 2017-12-31, 6:00, -1`, `2, ...`, `3, ...`. Correct? Please confirm, and also update this info in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The question is not clear. Actually, if in df_2 has the same id, date, and hour. The value are equal. So, we can chose the first row. For the second question, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

```
df_related_id = pd.DataFrame()
df_related_id ['id_1'] = [1, 2, 3,4]
df_related_id ['id_2'] = [10, 10, 10,5]

df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2['id_2'] = [10, 10, 10, 5,5, 30]
df_2['date'] = ['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-11-31','2017-11-31', '2017-12-31']
df_2 ['hour'] = ['6:00', '6:15', '6:00', '6:00', '6:00', '6:00']
df_2 ['val'] = [-1,12,-1,11,11,14]

df_2 = df_2.drop_duplicates()

df = pd.merge(df_related_id, df_2, how='left', on='id_2').drop('id_2', axis = 'columns')

print(df)

  id_1        date  hour  val
0     1  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
1     1  2017-12-31  6:15   12
2     2  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
3     2  2017-12-31  6:15   12
4     3  2017-12-31  6:00   -1
5     3  2017-12-31  6:15   12
6     4  2017-11-31  6:00   11
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct, provided that this is the actual logic the OP wants to apply. The post doesn't specify how to get from A to B